# Leitura de QR CODE com cordova

Tags: android, visual-studio, apache-cordova, mobile, cordova-plugin

Como faço para fazer a leitura de um QR CODE através do Cordova?

Já ví várias indicações de plugins mas nenhuma funcionou.

Obs:
Estou desenvolvendo utilizando o Visual Studio (não sei se existe alguma influência, por isso a informação)

Comment: Que plugins utilizou? Tem algum código da sua última tentativa para tentarmos perceber o que está a acontecer?

Comment: Cheguei nos plugin através de pesquisas no Google. Dava erro quando pegava o exemplo e mandava compilar. Você conhece algum plugin para indicação?

Comment: Nenhum plugin util encontrado .... Considerar como iniciar da estaca zero, pois estou iniciando com Cordova e tenho poucos conhecimentos ainda.

Answer (score -1):

O visual studio, não interfere em nada neste aspecto.

A visualização nativa da câmera do QRScanner é renderizada por trás do webview do aplicativo Cordova, e o QRScanner fornece showmétodos hidepara alternar a transparência do plano de fundo do webview. Isso permite que uma interface totalmente HTML/CSS/JS seja construída dentro do webview para controlar o scanner.

Dados no Git para instalação do plugin.

https://github.com/bitpay/cordova-plugin-qrscanner

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).